Getting Exception When Pair with MAC
Could not install workload 'ios'. Details: Unhandled exception: Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WorkloadManifestReader.WorkloadManifestCompositionException: Could not find workload 'ios' extended by workload 'maui-ios' in manifest 'microsoft.net.sdk.maui' [/Users/jaajitech/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/SDKs/dotnet/sdk-manifests/8.0.100/microsoft.net.sdk.maui/8.0.3/WorkloadManifest.json]
My Visual Studio 2022 is 17.9.5
My Mac Xcode version is 15.3

Xcode 15.3 is not supported at this time. You may follow this thread, [META] Xcode 15.3 Support for .NET 8 and MAUI. The workaround is to use XCode15.2 or dotnet/runtime#98941.

It appears to be a bug related to the Visual Studio version. However, you can resolve these issues with the following steps:

Copy the workload from your Windows machine located at:
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\8.0.100\microsoft.net.sdk.ios

Paste the copied workload into your Mac at the following path:
~/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/SDKs/dotnet/sdk-manifests/8.0.100/microsoft.net.sdk.ios

Then pair your Mac via Visual Studio. It should work as expected after this.


